# Get signal from apartment intercom to know when someone ring

Tags: transistors, esp8266, 12v

In my apartment I have an old intercom to know when someone is at the entrance of the building and to unlock the door. I waned to connect it to an esp8266 to let me know remotely if someone ring and to open. 
The opening part is ok, I used a relay for that.
But the tricky part is to be notified when someone ring.The intercom is running with 12v but when someone ring the current is going to 0v.

The intercom as only to cable. I tried to get signal by using this circuit. The idea is to detect current drop :

[image: detect ring circuit]

problem is: when nobody is ringing and 12v is present in the intercom wire, GPIO is going high and low constantly. Is there any reason for that ? Is there something wrong with this circuit ?

Comment: Are you sure it's 12V DC in that intercom circuit? Or just rectified AC but not well smoothed?

Comment: Not sure and my voltmeter do not say more than 12v. But it’s what I was wondering. If it’s the case what can I do to smooth it to 12v ?

Comment: Add a diode ahead of R2 (cathode at R2) , then a small cap and resistor (in parallel) to ground at Q1's base. Might try a 120k and 10nF to start. This would rectify any AC (and/or audio signals) on the line.

Comment: To the ground of the intercom you mean ? No risk to close the intercom circuit and get undesired behavior from it ?

Comment: Stray noise current needs to be absorbed. apply 10k across Vbe.  if it still toggles then you need a diode and cap on input

Comment: Your circuit ground should be at the common point of the cable, or where ever you measured the low end of the 12V.  The 120k should give safe isolation. (I would just add that you should be sure those lines are not in any way connected to AC line voltage).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your "12V" is AC, not DC. You could fix this in software by simply ignoring any high input that doesn't last for more than, say, 1 second.

Comment: Yes it’s what I did for the moment but I was not satisfied and a little bit scared of this behavior^^